# Select all values in one column that aren't in another table's column

Tags: sql

I have one table for `contributions` and another table for `profiles`. I want to `select all profiles` that have no associated contributions.

I can join the two tables on `contributions.profiles_id = profiles.id`.

Really appreciate any help!

Comment: This is commonly achieved with a `NOT EXISTS` and a correlated subquery, or a `LEFT JOIN` and then detecting missing joins by comparing any right table column to null.

Answer (score 2):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to find the profiles that have no associated contributions:

```
select * from profiles p
where NOT EXISTS (select 1 from contributions c
                  where c.profiles_id = p.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this.

select p.* from profiles p
left join contributions c on p.profile_id=c.profie_id 
where c.profile_id is NULL ;
```

Comment: assuming that c.profile_id is not a nullable column, I would go with that. if it is nullable, I would suggest using `not exists` instead.

Answer (score 0):

*The query what you need is:

```
SELECT 
    colA,
    colB,
    ....
FROM contributions tb1
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * from profiles tb2 where tb1.profiles_id = tb2.id )
GROUP BY
   colA,
   colB,
   ....
```

Comment: you can also use Not IN.`INSERT INTO tableA
(
     col1,
     col2
)
Select 
    colA,
    colB,
    ....
FROM
    contributions tb1
WHERE 
   tb1.profiles_id   NOT IN ( SELECT tb2.id from profiles tb2 group by tb2.id )
GROUP BY
   colA,
   colB,
   ....
;`

Comment: You're not answering the question. INSERT is not the answer.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, depends on the dbms used. (No one specified here...)

Comment: @jarlh in any dbms I've worked with, not exists is better then in for subqueries that might return a lot of rows.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I didn't know there are still dbms products not optimizing that... Anyway, my main dbms products have no problem at all, same execution plans.

Comment: @jarlh actually, I think sql server 2012+ should probably optimize it, I know from experience that 2008 r2 and older versions didn't.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I always say use NOT EXISTS, but that's because NOT IN is tricky when it comes to NULL values from the sub-select. (Probably one of the most common SQL programming mistakes...)

Comment: @AritraBhattacharya no point of having a columns list in the select inside the not exists. the optimizer will ignore it anyway. use * instead.

Comment: Correctly said @Zohar Peled a Select * would be sufficient